# How can I find all Sources and Destinations used in a SSIS package excluding disabled Data Flow Tasks

Tags: xml, visual-studio, ssis, dataflow, dataflowtask

I have this requirement at work, I need to list all the sources and destinations used in multiple SSIS packages for Inventory purposes. The packages are old and they have a lot of Data Flow Tasks that are disabled plus they are complex.

The sources and destinations in these packages include SQL Server, Excel and Flat files.

These packages are not deployed to SSISDB.

I tried to use a code editor to open the packages in XML format and search all the connection strings, but I can not tell if they are being used or disabled.

Therefore, I am currently downloading the packages from our repo and opening each package and Data Flow Tasks (which are several in all the packages) and listing the sources and destinations, which is a tedious task.

Does anyone know if there is an efficient and easier way to do this task?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Biml](http://www.varigence.com/bimlscript/) Reverse engineer your packages into the corresponding Biml. Drops the lines of code by 80+%. Then it's nested foreach loops. Foreach package in Root.Packages -> Foreach task in package.Tasks.Where(Type == "DataFlow") and then Foreach transformation in task.Transformations {inspect transformation, note connections, etc}